# Develop in the series of powers around the corresponding origin (Taylor or Laurent) the following functions...

Tags: complex-analysis

Develop in the series of powers around the corresponding origin (Taylor or Laurent) the
following functions, indicating the region of uniform convergence

$f(z)=\frac{sin(z)}{z}$

**My attempt:**
Note $f(z)$ is'n analytic in $z=0$.

Let $g(z)=\sin z$, as $g$ is holomorphic function then have a representation in Taylor series:

$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

This implies:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Is correct this?

How can i found the convergence region?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Well, they also asked about the region of convergence.

Comment: Power series converge on a disc with center at the point at which the expansion is done, $z=0$ in your case, and radius that can be computed with [these formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius), which arise from comparing the series of absolute value with geometric series. Expect the result of evaluating those formulas to be infinite, for your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cauchy-Hadamard.  Thus $r=1/\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n]{|(-1)^n/(2n+1)!|}=\infty$.