# Find the representation in series of $\displaystyle\int_0^z \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the representation in series of $\displaystyle\int_0^z \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$
**My attempt:**

For this: [Develop in the series of powers around the corresponding origin (Taylor or Laurent) the following functions...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572065/develop-in-the-series-of-powers-around-the-corresponding-origin-taylor-or-laure)

$f(z)=\frac{\sin t}{t}=\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$

Moreover, the radius of uniform convergence is $C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<\infty\}$

This implies:

$\displaystyle\int_0^z \frac{\sin t}{t}dt=\int_0^z\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}dt=\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^zt^{2n}dt=\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$

In convergence radius: $C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<\infty\}$

is correct this?

Comment: Yes, you have done it right.

Comment: The series converges for ALL complex numbers. There is NO complex number whose absolute value is infinity. The set of complex numbers is NOT the same as the complex projective line. There is a standard embedding from the set of complex numbers  C to the complex projective line defined by f(z)=(z:1) but f is NOT surjective, because (1:0) is not f(z) for any complex number z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the comments. Your approach and result are correct, except that a) you’ve specified the domain of convergence and called it the convergence radius, and b) your notation for the domain of convergence is unnecessarily complicated and confusing, since it coincides with $\mathbb C$.